# SOAPUI Error on asserts coming from the database

Tags: maven, jenkins, soapui, assertions

When I run the test cases inside soapUI, everything works fine. But when I'm running the tests inside jenkins, the assertions fail as you can see in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/1104276

I'm running the tests with maven command line tool. The errors are the same. And the same are the errors showing on the log files. I've been testing different ways to pass the values for the asserts, all working in the soapui IDE, but not on the command line.

Comment: I solved this running tests with ant instead of maven. Both can run in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check the assertion if you specified Ignorenamespace option.